# Citation undefined on input - citation appearing as question mark

Tags: bibliographies, mactex

I am quite new to using LaTeX and Mendeley. I am using the most up to date version of MacTeX and Mendeley desktop. I created a library.bib file (I checked the option 'create 1 BibTeX file for my whole library' which looks like this:

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.17.13
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

BibTeX export options can be customized via Preferences -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

@article{Lipson2017,
abstract = {Ancient DNA studies have established that European Neolithic populations were descended from Anatolian migrants who received a limited amount of admixture from resident hunter-gatherers. Many open questions remain, however, about the spatial and temporal dynamics of population interactions and admixture during the Neolithic period. Using the highest-resolution genome-wide ancient DNA data set assembled to date$\backslash$---|a total of 177 samples, 127 newly reported here, from the Neolithic and Chalcolithic of Hungary (6000-2900 BCE, n = 98), Germany (5500-3000 BCE, n = 42), and Spain (5500-2200 BCE, n = 37)$\backslash$---|we investigate the population dynamics of Neolithization across Europe. We find that genetic diversity was shaped predominantly by local processes, with varied sources and proportions of hunter-gatherer ancestry among the three regions and through time. Admixture between groups with different ancestry profiles was pervasive and resulted in observable population transformation across almost all cultural transitions. Our results shed new light on the ways that gene flow reshaped European populations throughout the Neolithic period and demonstrate the potential of time-series-based sampling and modeling approaches to elucidate multiple dimensions of historical population interactions.},
author = {Lipson, Mark and Sz{\'{e}}cs{\'{e}}nyi-Nagy, Anna and Mallick, Swapan and P{\'{o}}sa, Annam{\'{a}}ria and St{\'{e}}gm{\'{a}}r, Bal{\'{a}}zs and Keerl, Victoria and Rohland, Nadin and Stewardson, Kristin and Ferry, Matthew and Michel, Megan and Oppenheimer, Jonas and Broomandkhoshbacht, Nasreen and Harney, Eadaoin and Nordenfelt, Susanne and Llamas, Bastien and Mende, Bal{\'{a}}zs Guszt{\'{a}}v and K{\"{o}}hler, Kitti and Oross, Kriszti{\'{a}}n and Bond{\'{a}}r, M{\'{a}}ria and Marton, Tibor and Oszt{\'{a}}s, Anett and Jakucs, J{\'{a}}nos and Paluch, Tibor and Horv{\'{a}}th, Ferenc and Csengeri, Piroska and Ko{\'{o}}s, Judit and Sebok, Katalin and Anders, Alexandra and Raczky, P{\'{a}}l and Regenye, Judit and Barna, Judit P. and F{\'{a}}bi{\'{a}}n, Szilvia and Serlegi, G{\'{a}}bor and Toldi, Zolt{\'{a}}n and Nagy, Emese Gy{\"{o}}ngyv{\'{e}}r and Dani, J{\'{a}}nos and Moln{\'{a}}r, Erika and P{\'{a}}lfi, Gy{\"{o}}rgy and M{\'{a}}rk, L{\'{a}}szl{\'{o}} and Melegh, B{\'{e}}la and B{\'{a}}nfai, Zsolt and Fern{\'{a}}ndez-Eraso, Javier and Mujika-Alustiza, Jos{\'{e}} Antonio and Fern{\'{a}}ndez, Carmen Alonso and Echevarr{\'{i}}a, Javier Jim{\'{e}}nez and Bollongino, Ruth and Orschiedt, J{\"{o}}rg and Schierhold, Kerstin and Meller, Harald and Cooper, Alan and Burger, Joachim and B{\'{a}}nffy, Eszter and Alt, Kurt W. and Lalueza-Fox, Carles and Haak, Wolfgang and Reich, David},
doi = {10.1101/114488},
file = {:Users/zzzz/Documents/mendeley{\_}papers/Parallel palaeogenomic transects reveal complex genetic history of early European farmers.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0028-0836},
journal = {Nature},
pages = {114488},
publisher = {Nature Publishing Group},
title = {{Parallel ancient genomic transects reveal complex population history of early European farmers}},
url = {http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2017/03/06/114488},
year = {2017}
}
```

And my latex file looks like this (after having chopped out some stuff for brevity):

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\usepackage{geometry}                       % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                          % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                       % Activate for rotated page geometry
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Use pdf, png, jpg, or epsÂ§ with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                                % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%SetFonts

%SetFonts


\title{zzz}
\author{zzz}
\date{}                         % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Abstract}


zzzzz \cite{Lipson2017}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{/Users/zzzz/Documents/mendeley_papers/library.bib}
```

It compiles fine, but the reference is just a question mark within the text. And there is an error saying:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Lipson2017' on page 13 undefined on input line 183.

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Is there something obvious I am doing wrong? I've looked through all the other help threads but none of them solve my issue.

Comment: The standard answer is that you probably forgot to run BibTeX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 If you did run BibTeX and still nothing works, please check the `.blg` file for warnings or errors.

Answer (score 2):

in the line where you call the bibliography file,

```
\bibliography{/Users/zzzz/Documents/mendeley_papers/library.bib}
```

you need to remove ".bib" from the end of the path. Then it should work!

Comment: thanks it helped.